# Can I get a response from the server during upload? (C# UploadFileAsync)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, server, upload

I am using file upload using UploadFileAsync.

As soon as the server starts uploading, it sends a response to the request.

However, after the upload of the file is completed, you can receive the response.
(UploadFileCompleted is called after the upload is complete.)

Can I process the server's response during upload?

```
webClient.UploadFileCompleted += UploadFileCompletedCallback;
webClient.UploadProgressChanged += UploadProgressCallback;
webClient.UploadFileAsync("http://mydomain.test/upload.jsp", "C:\test.jpg");

private void UploadFileCompletedCallback(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("UploadFileCompletedCallback");
}

private void UploadProgressCallback(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("UploadProgressCallback : " + e.BytesSent + " / " + e.TotalBytesToSend);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to show upload progress to the client?

Comment: Yes. Clients must show upload progress.

Comment: Is the client posting the file to your controller?

Comment: What means controller? Client?

Comment: Is the client posting the file to your server? If so, then the client can show file progress uploading to server, the client shouldn't be concerned about how the upload progress is going on the _server_.

Comment: I am publishing files from Client to Server.

However, sometimes the server sends a response before all of the files have been uploaded.

I want to handle this.

Comment: You shouldn't care about that response. From a client perspective, my job is just to upload the files to the server and when that's done, my job is done. Those files are sitting on the server now and where it stores the files isn't a concern of the client.

Comment: In Java, uploads are completed when a response comes from the server while the entire file is being uploaded.

I'm wondering if .NET can do the same thing.

Comment: if you `await webClient.UploadFileAsync("http://mydomain.test/upload.jsp", "C:\test.jpg");` this line of code, then you won't get a response until file is uploaded.
`